# I'm having issue with data insertion through mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to perform data insertion in php **through mssql**.

But my problem is when I'm running my code using mysql it's working perfectly fine, but when I'm using mssql it's showing me error.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginphp\register.php on line 52 Error: Array

Here is screenshot of my data insertion query.

```
if (!$error) 
        {
            $tsql = "INSERT INTO dbo.users (
                name,
                email,
                password)
                VALUES
                (?, ?, ?)";
                $var = array($name, $email, $password);
                if(!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var))
                {
                    die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                 }
                echo "1 record added"; 
        }
```

Comment: chk connection errors

Comment: _"It's showing me error"_. It would be helpful if you shared the error you're getting.

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginphp\register.php on line 52
Error: Array

Comment: which one is line 52? in above code? also check `print_r($var);` what are u getting and share the result

Comment: @StutiRauthan: which is line 52 on your given code?

Comment: please echo $sql variable manually run SQL cmd  in MySQL database

Comment: @Ronald if(!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) this is my line number 52

Answer (score 0):

actually there was a  mistake in database field. Now my code is working fine. thank you so much everyone for your valuable time.